# tilde expansion fails when running "cd -" in bash

Tags: bash

Recently I find I can't use `cd -` to go back to last directory sometimes. It gives the error of `-bash: cd: ~/whatever_dir: No such file or directory`. A closer look shows that the error only happens if the last directory contains tilde. It seems tilde cannot be expanded. "cd ~", however, can successfully change to my home directory. What's the problem? I know tilde won't expand inside quotes, but the last directory stored is not in qotes when executing `cd -`, right? Plus, `cd -` worked for me previously.

Comment: What is the value of `$OLDPWD` when this phenomenon appears?

Comment: @fge: As seen by typing `echo "$OLDPWD"`, not `echo $OLDPWD`

Comment: @KeithThompson that doesn't matter for `echo`

Comment: @fge: It looks like you're right (but the quotation marks won't hurt, and remove some amount of uncertainty).

Comment: Both of the `echo` commands show `~/whatever_dir` correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The likely source of the problem, executed as part of `PROMPT_COMMAND` in your bash configuration:

```
PWD="${PWD/$HOME/~}"
```

Stop reassigning `PWD` to a different value. It will just break things.

Answer (score 0):

You have a serious bug in your shell which you should report. You said that in such a situation, `$OLDPWD` shows `~/whatever_dir`. It should not.

Here is what I have here:

```
fge@erwin ~/whatever_dir $ pwd
/home/fge/whatever_dir
fge@erwin ~/whatever_dir $ cd -
/home/fge
fge@erwin ~ $ echo $OLDPWD
/home/fge/whatever_dir
```

`~` is just a convenient shortcut used by shells to signify your home directory. Mine is `/home/fge`. In any event, `$OLDPWD` should show an absolute path, NOT a path with `~` in it, except if you do have a directory named `~`.